# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Loader::library() in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I have problem in opencart to start user panel to show error like this. I am install theme but show error. but by default theme is running is good.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Loader::library() in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopify\catalog\controller\journal2\settings.php on line 20
```

and code is setting.php file is

```
<?php
class ControllerJournal2Settings extends Controller {

private static $CACHEABLE = null;

private $css_settings = array();
private $js_settings = array();

protected $data = array();

protected function render() {
    return Front::$IS_OC2 ? $this->load->view($this->template, $this->data) : parent::render();
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->model('journal2/db');
    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    // admin mode
    $this->load->library('user');
    $this->user = new User($this->registry);
    if ($this->user->isLogged()) {
        $this->journal2->html_classes->addClass('is-admin');
    }

    // customer
    if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $this->journal2->html_classes->addClass('is-customer');
    } else {
        $this->journal2->html_classes->addClass('is-guest');
    }

    // get current store config settings
    $db_config_settings = $this->model_journal2_db->getConfigSettings();
    foreach ($db_config_settings as $key => $value) {
        $this->journal2->settings->set('config_' . $key, $value);
    }

    // get active skin
    $skin_id = $this->journal2->settings->get('config_active_skin', 1);

    if (!$this->model_journal2_db->skinExists($skin_id)) {
        $skin_id = 1;
    }
```

how to solve it.
please help.

Comment: Which version of Opencart are you using? You have installed both **Journal - Advanced Opencart Theme** & **Shopify**? I believe you will have to open a ticket to the **Journal Support Team** http://support.digital-atelier.com/. The will help you immediately.

Comment: I have use Journal_2.4.11

Comment: ...and which Opencart version?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, having tried Journal 2.3, 2.4.8 and 2.5.5; all with opencart 2.1.0.

Thank to this tutorial:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-registry-and-loader-objects-in-opencart--cms-23702

I noticed there was no function definition for library to call $this->load->library(); so I defined my as show below:

```
    public function library($library) {
        $file = DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/' . str_replace('../', '', (string)$library) . '.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            include_once($file);
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not load library ' . $file . '!');
            exit();
        }
    }
```

It worked for me, you may try it too.

Comment: in which file you added this function?

Comment: Sorry forgot to include that: `loader.php`: `../system/engine/loader.php`

Answer (score 1):

the issue is caused by the code:

```
$this->load->library('user');
```

which should only run for versions < 2.1

OpenCart versions come with code changes all the time and you should always update to the latest theme version, which always fixes this kind of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

When enabling OpenBayPro and the eBay extension, you might get a total site crash with the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Loader::library() in /xyz/system/library/openbay/ebay.php on line 146

There is a problem with the logging class which I haven't tracked down yet, but if you want your site back quickly just open the file `system/library/openbay/ebay.php` and comment out line 27, which will simply turn off the call to the logging for this extension:

Code (Select all):

```
if ($this->logging == 1) {
   //$this->setLogger();
}
```

**Source:**

- https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=181&t=153069

Answer (score 1):

This method was removed from 2.1.0.1, easier to add it back in manually by editing core file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
  <file path="system/engine/loader.php">
    <operation>
      <search index="0">
        <![CDATA[final class Loader {]]>
      </search>
      <ignoreif>
        <![CDATA[function library(]]>
      </ignoreif>
      <add position="after">
        <![CDATA[   public function library($library) {
        $file = DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/' . $library . '.php';

        if (file_exists($file)) {
            include_once($file);
        } else {
            trigger_error('Error: Could not load library ' . $file . '!');
            exit();
        }
    }]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
  </file>
</modification>
```